# How to handle duplicate IDs for inline SVGs?

Tags: php, css, svg

I am using the same SVG multiple times on a webpage. The SVGs are inserted on the server side with PHP like this:

`<?php echo file_get_contents("myimage.svg"); ?>`

The SVG contains a gradient, which should have different colors on different instances of the SVG.

An HTML document delivered by the server may look like the following snippet. The same SVG has been inserted twice:

```css
#image1 .stop1 { stop-color: #FDF39C }
#image1 .stop2 { stop-color: #FE8A77 }
#image2 .stop1 { stop-color: #64E8EA }
#image2 .stop2 { stop-color: #A79CFC }
```

```html
<div id="image1">
  <svg width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#gradient1)" cx="128" cy="128" r="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="image2">
  <svg width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#gradient1)" cx="128" cy="128" r="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

The problem is that both instances of the SVG display the gradient defined in the first SVG. Here is a comparison of the actual vs the intended result:

[image]

The reason for this is that the gradients of both inline SVGs have the same ID `gradient1`, because the same SVG which contains that ID is inserted twice on the server. The circle elements' fill is set to `url(#gradient1)` in both cases, which the browser simply links to the first occurence of that ID, which is the gradient definition in the first SVG. This behavior is correct, but for my case this is a problem.

The question is: How do I avoid duplicate ids? I worked with SVG injection using [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject), and this solved the problem by making the IDs unique. SVGInject simply adds a random string to the end of IDs, for example changing `gradient1` to `gradient1-h4w7xo82`.

However, I do not see a solution when inserting the SVGs with PHP. Can you help?

Comment: are you sure about your code? you have different ID and the result is good

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, I had changed the second ID for the screenshot and forgot to set it back before posting. I corrected this and now the code matches the question.

Comment: I think the solution is to create a php script thay generate a random ID that you append to the gradient ... you can for example have you svg like this `#gradient<token>` then you use string replace with php to replace `<token>` by a random ID generated with the same php script

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Special preparation of the SVG with `<token>` is an option in this simple case, but the SVGs are not always that simple. But creating a PHP script that adds a random token to the ID, just as SVGInject does, may be the way to go.

Comment: Here is a rough outline for a script to make the IDs of one SVG unique:

1. Generate a random token
2. Search for any occurrences of `id="..."` (where ... is the ID) within the `<def>...</def>` part of the SVG and insert the random string behind the ID. Store all original IDs in an array.
3. Run through the array of original IDs and insert the random token behind the ID for all occurrences of `url(#...)` (where ... is the ID).
With some clever regular expressions this should not be too difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Based Solution**
I was having the same problem.

The solution to the above problem is, change the css class, so that different css class is targeting different object.

Change -

1. CSS Class of 2nd element, I have change it to  `#image2 .stop1-df`, appended additional `"df"`
2. Linear Gradient ID - of second element - `gradient1-df`
3. Circle fill url - `#gradient1-df`

```css
#image1 .stop1 { stop-color: #FDF39C }
#image1 .stop2 { stop-color: #FE8A77 }
#image2 .stop1-df { stop-color: #64E8EA }
#image2 .stop2-df { stop-color: #A79CFC }
```

```html
<div id="image1">
  <svg width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#gradient1)" cx="128" cy="128" r="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="image2">
  <svg width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient1-df">
        <stop class="stop1-df" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2-df" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#gradient1-df)" cx="128" cy="128" r="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the svg file into php so you can pass the `gradientId` parameter into it.

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

  echo '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="' . $gradientId . '">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#' . $gradientId . ')" cx="128" cy="128" r="100" />
  </svg>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ it will convert all styles to URL-parameters, like this: id="a" and url("a"). If you want multiple SVGs on one page, they interfere with eachother.
I needed to have several SVGs on the same page, so I made a small util for my self. It will replace those a/b/c urls with a parameter you can insert for your self, so you can have 1 SVG with one_a, one_b etc and the second SVG with second_a, second_b etc. It uses regex, obviously:

```
# replace id="a" with id="test_a"
removeStr = "id=\"#{strChar}\""
regex =  new RegExp(removeStr,'g')
strInput = strInput.replace(regex,"id=\"#{strName}_#{strChar}\"")
```

You can find it here:
https://codepen.io/pwiegers/pen/YzreGGo

It saved me a ton of time; it might save you some :-)

Comment: This only works for ids that are only one letter

Comment: Yeah... that is ttue. I figured 26 different ones would be enough. But you are of course free to fork it and make an updated version :-)